# How to make Select2 infitine scroll pagination on server side and client side

Tags: pagination, infinite-scroll, jquery-select2-4

On documentation page there is no server side explanation. As Im confused, I want to solve my problem and maybe make a reference with server side and client side code.

I'm trying to make select2 (using v.4.0) infinite scroll pagination as a searchbox, but confused with `params.page`. How can I get that parameter as query request and return the page number for infinite scroll. How infinite scroll triggers? Below are my codes which I can only get 10 results.

HTML part of my code is;

```
<select id="search_products" name="q"></select>
```

JS part is;

```
jQuery('#search_products').select2({        
    ajax: {
        url: "search_results.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page_limit: 10,
            page:params.page
          };
        },

        processResults: function (data, params) {

        params.page = params.page || 1;

        return {
          results: data.items,
          pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total           
          }
        };

      },            
        cache: true
      },
      escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
      minimumInputLength: 3,
      templateResult: formatRepo,
      templateSelection: formatRepoSelection
});

function formatRepo (repo) {
    if (repo.loading) return repo.adi;

    var markup = '<div class="clearfix">' +        
    '<div class="col-sm-7">' + repo.name + '</div>' +
    '<div class="col-sm-4"><i class="fa fa-barcode"></i> ' + repo.barkod + '</div>';

    return markup;
  }

  function formatRepoSelection (repo) {
    return repo.adi;
  }
```

Server side - PHP part (`search_results.php`) is:

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['q']) && !empty($_REQUEST['q'])) {

    $q = getVar('q', 'anp'); //getVar is my custom sanitation function
    $pglm = getVar('page_limit', 'int');
    $page_lim = (empty($pglm) ? 10 : $pglm);
    $pg = getVar('page', 'int');
    $page =  (empty($pg) ? 0 : $pg);
    $sira = $page*$page_lim;

    //using MYSQL, querying with custom database query class $db
    $qu = $db->get_results("
                    SELECT * FROM  `products` 
                    WHERE  `adi` LIKE  '%$q%'
                    OR  `ozellikleri` LIKE  '%$q%'
                    OR  `ozet` LIKE  '%$q%'
                    OR  `barkod` LIKE  '%$q%' LIMIT $sira, $page_lim
                    ");

    if($qu && count($qu) > 0) {
        foreach ($qu as $oqu) {
            $items[] = array('name' => $oqu->adi, 'id' => $oqu->id,  'barkod' => $oqu->barkod);
            } 

        echo json_encode(array('items' => $items, 'total' =>  count($qu), 'page' => $page));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in your console? And are you sure that you are generating your `LIMIT` properly? The JS side of things looks correct here.

Comment: No exceptions. As I understand `params.page` is the current page number. Problem is how can I send this number to server. In PHP code I tried to get as  `$pg = getVar('page', 'int');` but it doesnt take action.

Answer (score 2):

There's issues on your code, both on client-side and server-side.

On client-side, try replacing this:

```
data: function (params) {
    return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page_limit: 10,
        page:params.page
    };
},
processResults: function (data, params) {
    params.page = params.page || 1;
    return {
        results: data.items,
        pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 30) < data.total           
        }
    }
};
```

For this:

```
var limit_rows = 10;
...
data: function (params) {
    return {
        q: params.term, // search term
        page_limit: limit_rows,
        page:params.page
    };
},
processResults: function (data, params) {
    params.page = params.page || 1;
    return {
        results: data.items,
        pagination: {
            more: (params.page * limit_rows) < data.total           
        }
    }
};
```

That way, select2 will parse page limit correctly, accordingly to "limit_rows" variable. Notice that I changed 30 for "limit_rows" var, inside "processResults" method, and now the field shows correctly 10 results per search.

On server-side, two issues:

- Your total count is wrong. You need to return total rows without LIMIT on your query. That'll avoid return total as always the value from your page limit (in your case, 10).
- Your array being returned as json is missing some info. Try changing this:

  echo json_encode(
      array(
          'items' => $items,
          'total' =>  count($qu),
          'page' => $page)
  );

For this:

```
echo json_encode(
    array(
        'incomplete_results' => false,
        'items' => $items,
        'total' => count($qu) // Total rows without LIMIT on your SQL query
);
```

That worked for me.